# ts-jest is not transpiling modules imported with Dynamic Imports

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I am using dynamic imports in my nodejs code to import some modules. Ex:

```
const initialize = (await import('./init')).default;
await initialize();
```

But when i run `jest`, it throws the following error:

```
import sequelize from 'sequelize';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I am assuming that `ts-jest` is not transforming/transpiling the code that is imported dynamically.

My `jest.config.js` file has:

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    rootDir: './src/test',
    globalSetup: '../setup/test_setup.ts',
};
```

Please advice on how to resolve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was occurring when the `globalSetup` code was being run. Not sure if `ts-jest` doesn't transpile `globalSetup` code.

To fix the issue, I added this to the top of the `test_setup.ts` file (which has the globalSetup code):

```
require('ts-node').register({ transpileOnly: true });
```

(https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/411#issuecomment-850944698)

You need to install `ts-node` for this to work.